# Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver on google compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I am trying to deploy on **google compute engine** .During deployment i am getting following error.

**"Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver]".**

In  appengine-web.xml true it is set to **true**  and mysql connector-jar(5.1.30) is also present in lib of tomcat.It seems like  file
appengine-web.xml automatically handles google driver .But,it is not happening

**What else configuration have i missed?** .Help me please .Thank You

Comment: Configuration file `appengine-web.xml` has nothing to do with Compute Engine. It is used by App Engine. What service do you use?

Comment: I am using putty not gsutil.

Answer (score 1):

From Google Compute Engine you should use the [stock MySQL Java connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. You will need to set up an IP address and grant access to your Compute Engine's IP address, as outlined at https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external.